# A Mozzie Murder

Tags: knowledge

While we see Mozzies as pests they are more civilized than you'd think. In fact they have laws and police in their society.

Which is why on this unfortunate day, the investigation into the murder of Max the Mozzie is taking place.

As a senior Mozzie in society, having bitten thousands of humans, you have been asked to be the judge. There are 5 suspects each who have there own story about what they were doing at the time the murder took place.

> **Suspect 1 - Anne**
>
> 'I was feeding on a deer that came to drink at the river'
>
> **Suspect 2 - Jack**
>
> 'I was sleeping in a hollow tree in the woods'
>
> **Suspect 3 - Ella**
>
> 'I was flying around a swamp looking for food'
>
> **Suspect 4 - John**
>
> 'I was biting a human who was bird watching'
>
> **Suspect 5 - Steve**
>
> 'I was trying to avoid being eaten by a bird'

### You're the judge, Whodunnit?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's a Mozzie?  Or is figuring that out important to the puzzle?

Comment: Mozzie is slang for mosquito.  I first heard it when I moved to Australia, not sure where else it's used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming Mozzie actually means mosquito, not something trickier...

> John did it, male mosquitoes don't bite, they eat nectar.

Comment: you wouldn't have thought John was that stupid though

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Kind of like a woman giving an "I was peeing in a urinal" alibi.

Comment: @DanRussell; or a cat saying she was chasing a dog!

Comment: This is correct. Well done. This was just a short brainteaser. Glad someone got it :)